# How to Optimize more than one equations simultaneously?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, optimal-control

I need to Optimize two equations simultaneously, Is there an algorithm to do that? For example I am working on the below equations: 
$F(x,y,z,t) = (xy - zt)^2$  where to optimize the difference between those two multiplications doesn't mean to optimize the xy and zt separately. for example, is xy equals to 6 and zt equals 6.1, so the absolute value is equals to 0.1, but xy and zt themselves are not optimized which are 6 and 6.1.

what I need is to optimize those equations simultaneously:

$F(x,y,z,t) = (xy - zt).^2$   and $F21(x,y) = xy$  and $F22(z,t) = zt;$

is that possible?
I was thinking to used Lagrange multipliers, and use constraints, but in Lagrange multipliers, it doens't mean the constraints are optimized also? is that right.

Is there any method or algorithm to make that optimization? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to think about your problem a little more.

Before you even start on any kind of multiple objective optimization scheme, notice that the set of variables $(x,y)$ and $(z,t)$ are not mutually identifiable since they only appear in the form $xy$ and $zt$. Any values satisfying $xy=zt$ will be optimizers of your quadratic function.

Also, what does it mean to *optimize* the product $xy$ or $zt$? This function can take on any real value, so this doesn't mean much without clarification. If you are referring to adding *constraints*, such as $xy=2$, $zt=-3$, or $x+z=10$, for example, then these can make your problem better posed and the method of Lagrange multipliers can be used to solve these problems.

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for your comment. Yes I totally agree with you that any value satisfying xy=zt will be optimizers, but that doesn't mean that xy itself  or zt will be optimized. I mean for example if xy = 6 and zt = 6, then the function F will will optimized but xy and zt won't optimized since they will be 6 or around that, so that I need xy and zt be optimized too. ok, let's suggest what's  about if  F(x,y,z,t) = {(xy).^2 - (zt).^2} ? then can we optimize this make? Hope that you got my idea, what I need is to optimize the function F with respect to all variables.

Comment: @Zeyad_Zeyad But $F(x,y,z,t) = (xy)^2 - (zt)^2$ is not convex and will have the solution that $xy=0$ and $zt=\pm\infty$. An alternative would be $F(x,y,z,t) = (xy - zt)^2 + c_1 (xy)^2 + c_2 (zt)^2$ with $c_1$ and $c_2$ some positive constants.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "optimizing" the products $xy$ and $zt$? Of you mean minimizing their absolute value or something then that is possible. Let $u=xy$ and $v=zt$.  Then your problem can be posed as: Minimize $$(u-v)^2 +u^2 + v^2, $$ which has a unique minimum at $u=v=0$.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Thank you so much for your comment. So, you mean is to  optimize F(x,y,z,t)=(xy−zt)2+c1(xy)2+c2(zt)2 using Lagrange multiplier, is that right? or another algorithm would  be easier?. What I understood is to optimize  F(x,y,z,t)=(xy−zt).^2 with constraints of (xy).^2 = 0 and (zt).^2 = 0.  is that right?  please correct me if i'm right or not.  Thanks again.

Comment: @whpowell96 ,  Many thanks for your feedback, Yes it's to minimize their absolute value. I agree with you that minimizing  (xy - zt).^2 + u.^2 + v.^2 means to minimize xy, zt and the difference between their product which is (xy - zt) simultaneously. yes that's great. should I make that minimization using Lagrange multipliers or you suggest another method better than it.  Thank you again so much.

Comment: Hello all, now I'm checking your answers, is to put the F(x,y,z,t)=(xy−zt)2+(xy)2+(zt)2 , Either to include the c1, c2 or not .. the question, could we used gradient descent stochastic to optimize it? Or the alone way it using Lagrange multipliers ? ... Thank you so much

Comment: @Zeyad_Zeyad You only use Lagrange multipliers when you have constraints. I assume you do have other constraints, otherwise you will indeed not have a unique solution as whpowell96 stated. In this case $c_1$ and $c_2$ are just weights, which allows you to shift the emphasis of which part of the cost function you want to minimize the most.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen you mean no way to optimize such function like that? So what do you suggest ? what's about if we suggested (xy - zt)^2 and consider y and t as constants? .. Or what's about if minimizing (xy - zt).^2 + u.^2 + v.^2 and put x - z = 0 as constraint and use lagrange multiplier, I think that would be feasible. is it right?

Comment: Your function does not have unique minimizers. Obviously we can minimize it, but there are infinitely many choices that do so. It is still unclear to me what you are even trying to ask, so I suggest you think about your problem and clarify to yourself what you actually want out of this exercise and it will help you find a method to solve your problem

Comment: Actually the problem is, I have two variables x and y, which should have a results of multiplication equals to zero,  those two variables must equals to other two variables z and t, and their multiplication must equals to zero too. SO my goal now, is to get an optimizer for that function, which should optimize the difference of their product and also optimize their product with each other, I mean x*y  and z*t should equal to zero, and and at the same time x*y - z*t equals to zero too.  Of course, I need to optimize the absolute value. SO, is there a solution for that? does my function right?

Comment: Hope that my problem is clear now, .. to optimize xy and xy - zt simultaneously.  Is there a method for doing that?  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Zeyad_Zeyad So you basically have a set of equality constraints ($x\,y=0$, $x-z=0$ and $y-t=0$, the forth $z\,t=0$ is just a combination of the other constraints). You can use Lagrange multipliers for that. Or just use the algebraic solutions $x=z=0$ and $y=t=c$, or $x=z=c$ and $y=t=0$, with $c$ some constant.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen  You mean to use the main function F(x,y,z,t)=(xy−zt)2 with equality constraints  (xy=0, x−z=0 and y−t=0, the forth zt=0 is just a combination of the other constraints)? is that what you mean?

Comment: and finally what's about this: Let $u=xy$ and $v=zt$. Then your problem can be posed as: Minimize $$(u-v)^2 +u^2 + v^2, $$ which has a unique minimum at $u=v=0$  suggested by whpowell96, I think that's really good if we could optimize it, just I need in which method we can optimize that function, can I use for example gradient descent ? Thanks again.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Could you I please have more details about this suggestion: F(x,y,z,t)=(xy−zt)2+c1(xy)2+c2(zt)2  .. what do you mean by c1 and c2, and how can we optimize this equation? ..  Thank you so much in advance.